# DataTable in SweetAlert2 Pop-Up

Tags: jquery, database, datatables, sweetalert2

Is this possible or am I wasting my time?

Tried many things.

First of all I have

```
$html = listings_swal()
```

which is

```
function listings_Swal() {
    return '<table id="datatable"><thead><tr><th>Col1</th><th>Col2</th></tr></thead>
    <tfoot><tr><th>Col1</th><th>Col2</th></tr></tfoot></table>';
```

Which is just simply the empty table without the contents.

Here is my target link to open the SweetAlert Dialogue:

```
<a id="listings">Listings</a>
```

and my script:

```
  echo "<script>
$('#listings').on('click', function(){
  swal({
    title: 'Listings',
    html:'" . $html . "',
    showCancelButton: false,
  showConfirmButton: false,
  showCloseButton: true}, function() {
      $.ajax({
    url: 'listings.js',
    dataType: 'script'
      })
      .done(function(data) {
        swal('Deleted!', 'our file was successfully deleted!', 'success');
      })
      .error(function(data) {
        swal('Oops', 'We couldnt connect to the server!', 'error');
      });
    });
     });
</script>";
```

In my `listings.js` file

I have the standard Datatable init

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#datatable').dataTable({
     .....
```

I've tried a few things with no success.

Such as adding the script after the sweetalert dialogue

```
  echo "<script>
$('#listings').on('click', function(){
  swal({
    title: 'Table',
    html:'" . $html . "',
    showCancelButton: false,
  showConfirmButton: false,
  showCloseButton: true
  })
});
</script>";
echo '<script src="listings.js"></script>';
```

I've also tried doing a php ajax return in my sweetalert script `table.php` which just had an `echo '<script src="listings.js"></script>';`

I've tried modifying my listings_Swal() function so that after the closing `</table><script src="listings.js"></script>` the script is added.

This all works fine if it's not within a sweetalert2 dialogue pop-up--- and the sweetalert dialogue does indeed work, but the table is not populated with the DataTable contents (it just simply shows the `<table><thead>` and `<tfoot>` with no table rows generated from DataTables.

I am certain that my scripts otherwise work fine and populate the table rows if they are not in the sweetalert2 dialogue box and just normal html table, so I am confused as to how to get DataTables to init the loading of the table rows within the sweet alert pop-up itself.

Not sure what else I can try.  Is it something with the DOM not recognizing the table to initialize the Datatable?  Anyone have any ideas?

Thank you!

edit: To clarify, as I said the sweetalert2 dialogue does pop-up just does not populate it with datatable's rows, and no console/js errors to be shown so I'm not sure how to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. I guess I had to separate the two. Do the SweetAlert command (swal), and then the Datatable command.

```
<script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
$('#listings').on('click', function(){
  Swal.fire({
    title: 'Listings',
    html: '<?php echo $html; ?>'
});
    $('#datatable').DataTable( {
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": false,
    "ajax": "scripts/server_processing.php"
  } )
    });
});
</script>
```

Works as expected!